# VS 2017 C++ compiler cannot find matching function was OK in VS 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am getting

> "error C3861: 'to8Bit': identifier not found" in this situation:

```
typedef struct _ustruct2
{
    int which;
    union 
    {
        double d;
        tstring  * s;
        bool b;
        char e;
    } uu;
} ustruct2;

std::string  to8Bit(const std::string &s);
std::string  to8Bit(const std::string s);
std::string  to8Bit(const tstring s);
std::string  to8Bit(tstring s);
std::string  to8Bit(tstring &s);
std::string  to8Bit(wchar_t * pc);
std::string  to8Bit(const tstring &s);
std::string  to8Bit(const char * pc, int len = -1);
std::string  to8Bit(const wchar_t * pc, int len = -1);

static void outputustruct(FILE * opmte, int i, const char * s, const ustruct2 &u)
{
    std::string mys2 = to8Bit((*u.uu.s).c_str());
}
```

There are some other versions of `to8BIT` that I don't think are needed in this post.  But I would have thought one of these would match.  I have tried getting rid of the const and/or the ampersand in the function outputustruct function header, and removing the asterisk in the call to `to8Bit` when the ampersand is removed.  I have tried string and tstring in the struct definition and the code with the error on it, but nothing I do gets it to compile.

This code works fine in VS 2005 but not in VS 2017.  In my experience MS tightens the compiler in later versions to more strictly conform to standards but I can't see what's causing the compiler error here.

Comment: It is impossible to overload on value vs const reference.

Comment: I have a couple of to8Bit prototypes without the const.  If I remove the const from the third argument to the outputustruct function I still get the same error.

Comment: @SergeyA It isn't, but good luck calling either overload ;)

Comment: OP you cannot be getting _that_ error from this code. I would expect an ambiguous call but not that. Please present your [MCVE].

Comment: Why are you using `typedef struct _tagname`? That is C and completely unnecessary in C++. In C++, you simply define `struct ustruct2 {...}`

Comment: Are you focusing on the correct error?  It is a plain "identifier not found", it is not fretting over not finding a matching or ambiguous overload.  You might have hidden the real problem by making it look like this code is all in one source file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, all right, i guess, you win on the technicality. ;)

Comment: Do you have a typo in here `to8Bit(*u.uu.s).c_str())` 2 open braces, and 3 closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 `std::wstring_convert` (deprecated in C++17) provides a simple solution:

In your case, tstring defined as:

```
#include <tchar.h> // For _TCHAR

typedef std::basic_string<_TCHAR> tstring;
```

it is possible to convert like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    tstring string_to_convert = L"Follow the white rabbit";

    // Converter setup:
    using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

    // Convert (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
    std::string converted_str = converter.to_bytes(string_to_convert);

    return 0;
}
```

or in your case, something like:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

static void outputustruct(FILE * opmte, int i, const char * s, const ustruct2 &u)
{
    // Converter setup:
    using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

    // Convert:
    string mys2 = converter.to_bytes(*u.uu.s);
}
```

(This works on VS2017 C++)

Comment: I apologize in advance for my confusion when it comes to strings and characters.  Is the change you made to ustruct2 where you have "std::tstring  * ts;" instead of "tstring  * s;" impacting anything? I don't want to break anything else in the larger project. That said I get the error "error C2039: 'tstring': is not a member of 'std'" in the struct definition and "error C2065: 'USES_CONVERSION': undeclared identifier" Is there something missing?

Comment: I left the definition of ustruct2 as it was originally, in case that matters.  I get "error C2039: 'codecvt_utf8': is not a member of 'std'" and "error C2039: 'wstring_convert': is not a member of 'std'"  When you say wstring_convert was deprecated in 2017 do you mean VS2017? If so isn't that a problem since I'm upgrading to VS2017?

Comment: @RichT #include <locale> and #include <codecvt>

Comment: No luck: error C2664: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> std::wstring_convert<convert_type,wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t>,std::allocator<char>>::to_bytes(const _Elem *,const _Elem *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'tstring' to 'wchar_t'

Comment: @RichT tstring is not a standard C++ type. I assumed you have somewhere in your code something like: #ifdef _UNICODE
#define tstring std::wstring
#else
#define tstring std::string
#endif . What is your tstring definition?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it was a part of C++ because when I looked online tstring was listed on other sites. I was also mixed up with the compiler directive "Treat Wchar_t as a built in type" which saw the "t" and jumped to a stupid conclusion (I have it set to No by the way).  The line I fond in my code is: typedef std::basic_string<_TCHAR> tstring; and it looks like TCHAR is part of the language or extensions.

Comment: Interesting but does not appear to answer this question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sometimes someone ask: "How do I take a Taxi from NYC to LA?". And the best answer is: "You take a flight". It's not the answer to the question, but it's the answer to the problem.

Comment: @AmitG. Then offering to rephrase/improve the question is appropriate, but this is a Q&A! You answer the question asked :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I offered to rephrase the question to: "How to convert std::basic_string<_TCHAR> to std::string in VS2017 C++?" but my suggestion rejected.

Comment: @AmitG.: Right, because it's a completely different question :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @AmitG. Yes, I've heard of it. It's overinvoked. Just linking to that article doesn't mean you can write random answers to completely unrelated questions :P